# Element shakes when stop a css transition on iOS device

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, transition

as we know the only way to stop a css transition is setting the element to the current position(computed style for transform & translate) and set the "transition-duration" as "0s". i stop the transition successfully. but there is a problem on iOS device:

when i stop the transition, the element will stop and shake a little bit. i found that the reason is when we get the computed style for the element and set transform value, the element will still going for a short distance, and then stop on the position which we got.

this ONLY appears on iOS device. it works correctly in Chrome on my mac, even in developer tool with iPhone6 mode.

is there anyone found the same problem as i got?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beU1J.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After countless experiments, the only reliable solution I found is ... not to use CSS transitions. This is iOS bug (reproduced on Safari and Chrome) and you can do nothing about it other than wait and hope it will be fixed in the future.

If you are using jQuery (preferably jQuery3 as it has better animation performance), then you can animate "transform" property like this:

```
$element[0].foo = 0;

$element.animate({ foo : 1 }, {
  step: function(now, fx) {

    $(this).css( 'transform', 'translate(' + ( startX + ( (endX - startX) * now) ) + 'px, ' + ( startY + ( (endY - startY) * now) ) + 'px)' );

  },
  duration : speed
});
```

And later just use `.stop()` to stop animation without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

enable the 3D engine by doing a transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0).